# finite (non-disjoint) open covering a finite set

Tags: real-analysis

A collection of sets $O_{\lambda}$ open covers a set $A$ in $\bf R$ that is bounded and measurable. Assume that $A$ can not be open covered by a finite subcollection of $O_{\lambda}$, let $\epsilon>0$. Is there a finite subcollection of $O_{\lambda}$, denote $O_n$ (don’t have to be disjoint), such that $m^*(A\setminus\bigcup O_n)<\epsilon$?

Also, is it equivalent to say "the subset of $A$ that can not be finitely open covered by some subcollection of $O_{\lambda}$ has measure 0" ? edit: (this paragraph is not mathematically constructed right,
attribute to Wong pointing it out, but would happy to take other good alternate rephrases)

Comment: I think it might be helpful to mention vitali's lemma as a good comparison. Vitali's lemma, as far as i understand, from royden's real analysis, states the conditions roughtly the same, except that, the sets Oλ covers A in a sense of vitali, and on top of that, the finite subcollection of Oλ are disjoint. Which are two very very interesting differences

Comment: I've added some formatting, please check to see that I haven't messed anything up.

Comment: yep it's perfectly correct, thx!

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Instead of general $A$ it's enough to consider simply $\ A:=\bigcup_\lambda\,O_\lambda.$

Comment: i am not sure if i understand what you mean by considering a specific example of A. Thanks for an editing of better formatting btw.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is inner regular. Let $K$ be an compact subset of $A$ with $m(A\setminus K) < \epsilon$. Then take the finite subcover $O_n$ of $K$. // I don't understand your final paragraph, mainly because the phrase "the subset of $A$ that cannot be finitely open covered" makes no sense to me. (It is like saying "the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is not finite".)

Comment: You are right, the last paragraph is not making sense

Comment: I think the idea of Lebesgue measure is inner regular is really really close to what I am actually wondering about. The difference is that, the idea that Lebesgue measure is inner regular, are having the intervals, or the compact sets, lots of freedom of construction, possibly i believe it actually covers the set A in a sense of vitali, whereas, in my question, the intervals don't have that freedom, the only thing that they have is their union is an open cover of A

Comment: in other words, i am not sure how i can make valid of your statement of "then take the finite subcover $O_{\lambda}$ of K" as that was never given, for that family of sets $O_{\lambda}$